# Hdfs file Unix to Dos

Tags: linux, scala, hdfs, rdd

I have a file in HDFS in Unix format and need to change it to DOS format.

I cannot use commands because I don't have permissions on the Linux machine with my rol user.

I can not replace line breaks (\n, \r\n) because I can not get into the text file to read (will slow the process, more than 1 million lines). Also the text file is a RDD (Spark).

I need to know how I can implement the HDFS in DOS format or convert it somehow with some Java or Scala service.

Comment: " can not replace line breaks (\n, \r\n) because I can not get into the text file to read (will slow the process, more than 1 million lines). " This makes no sense. That's what "changing it to DOS format" is. Also, it can't both be a text file and also be an RDD?

Comment: I think I have not explained very well.
I generate a TXT file through a process that introduces a strings that come in a RDD. By using the HDFS (Unix) format when I open the file in a DOS system the line breaks do not appear. I need to know how replace the string "\ r" for "\ r \ n" in the process.

`val result = Try (rdd.saveAsTextFile (imputFullPath))`

Comment: Why not just postprocess the file after you've generated it, perhaps as part of the process of transferring it to the DOS system?

Comment: Finally I solved my problem with:  `val filtered = contentfile.map({ line => line.concat("\r")})`

Comment: Great, but that's just doing what you said you couldn't do in the question :)